# CakePHP 2 how to do multiple pagination with same model

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0

So, I have 1 view, and I need to do pagination for 2 tables for the same model, but different conditions. e.g:

```
Task Model --> 1st pagination --just paginate task assigned to me
           --> 2nd pagination --paginate task created by me
```

Is there anyway to do this?

```
    public function dashboard() {
        $this->layout = 'user';
        $limit = 5;
//debug($this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'));
//debug($this->Session->read('Auth.User.group_id'));

        //My Task Pagination
        $this->paginate = array(
            'Project' => array(
                'limit' => $limit,
                //'contain' => array('ProjectReminderUser.user_id =' . $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'User.group_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.group_id'),
                    //'ProjectReminderUser.user_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'),
                ),
            )
        );
        $this->set('myTasks', $this->paginate('Project'));  
        //debug($this->paginate('Project'));

        //Group Task Pagination
        $this->paginate = array(
            'Project' => array(
                'limit' => $limit,
                //'contain' => array('ProjectReminderUser.user_id =' . $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'User.group_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.group_id'),
                    //'ProjectReminderUser.user_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'),
                ),
            )
        );
        $this->set('groupTasks', $this->paginate('Project'));   
        //debug($this->paginate('Project'));        
    }
```

This code still hasn't differentiated the conditions yet.
But I was wondering how I can do this. Because with my current code, every time I try to sort or move pages, it will do the same to both tables due to the same model.

Comment: By default CakePHP most likely uses "page:2" in your URL for both paginations. Have you made changes needed for pagination to use parameters in URL correctly? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#pagination-with-get-parameters

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem several days ago. At my experience I found the best solution from http://deadlytechnology.com/php/paginate-multiple-data-sets/ upto now. Although it's a very old post but I think this is the best solution for all types of multiple pagination i.e. same model multiple pagination, multiple model same view pagination etc.

**Solution:**
One pagination load as usual using CakePHP. Another one load using AJAX Request from another action from any controller. It will be interactive and meaningful if you use AJAX pagination for both pagination.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in Model::find() params 'page' and limit :

exemple :

```
$params=array('conditions'=>$conditions,'limit'=>$limitByPage,'page'=>$page );
$this->Model->find('all',$params);
```

just set the $limitByPage , and $page .
if you want to know number of page just find with a "count" / $limitByPage .

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple iframes to load the pagination independently.
I know it's late but hope can help those who are experiencing this problem.